# If second distributional derivative of $f$ is zero, what kind of a function is $f$?

Tags: distribution-theory

Given a continuous function $f$ such that
$\int f(x)\phi''(x) =0 $ for all $\phi$ $\epsilon$ $D(R).$

Then what can we say about $f$? The problem is straightforward if $f$ $\epsilon$ $C^2$
Kindly provide an answer with a proof.

Comment: Let $\phi''=\delta$ and then...

Comment: @ZacharySelk. Since $\phi \in D(\mathbb R) = C_c^\infty(\mathbb R),$ the space of compactly supported and infinitely differentiable functions on $\mathbb R,$ your suggestion is not possible.

Comment: @Siddhu, what can you say about $f$ when $f \in C^2(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: $f$ is a linear function if $f$ $\epsilon$ $C^2$, follows from integration by parts formula.

Comment: One way to solve this is to treat $f$ as a distribution and show that we then must have $f(x) = ax + b$ (as a distribution!) and then that also $f(x) = ax+b$ as a function.

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma** If $u$ is a distribution, and $u'=0$, then $u$ is constant (i.e. the distribution given by a constant function).

**Sketch of proof:**
$$u'=0 \Leftrightarrow u'(\phi)=0 \forall \phi \Leftrightarrow u(\phi')=0 \forall \phi$$

Now, fix one text function $\psi$ with $\int_{\mathbb R} \psi=1$ and define $C:=u(\psi)$.

Then, for each test function $\phi$ the function 
$$\phi_1(x):= \phi(x)- (\int_{\mathbb R} \phi(t) dt) \psi(x)$$
satisfies 
$$\int_{\mathbb R} \phi_1(x) dx$$

Pick some $a$ outside $\supp(\phi)$ and show that this implies that 
$$\phi_2(x)=\int_a^x \phi_1(t) dt$$
is also a test function.

Then, we have
$$0=u(\phi_2')=u(\phi_1)=u(\phi)-\int_{mathbb R} C \phi(t) dt $$

This gives that $u=C$.

**Lemma** If $u$ is a distribution, and $u''=0$, then $u=aX+b$, that is $u$ is the regular distribution given by this linear function.

**Proof:** Let $v=u'$. Then $v'=0$ implies that $v=a$ for some constant $a$.

Let 
$$w=u-aX$$
Then $w'=u'-a=v-a=0$, thus by the above lemma, $u-ax$ is constant.

**Conclusion of your exercise**

Consider the distribution $u_f$ given by $f$. Then $u_f''=0$ thus $u_f$ is also the distribution given by a linear function $ax+b$. Then $f=ax+b$ almost everywhere, and hence, by continuity $f=ax+b$.